# How to select rows with max date older then some value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have **Microsoft SQL Server 2008** and a table with data like this:

```
id | file_date [datatime] | file_path [varchar(255)]
____________________________________________________
1  |  01-01-1999          |   C:\f1.txt
2  |  01-01-2020          |   C:\f2.txt
3  |  05-05-1999          |   C:\f3.txt
4  |  05-05-2020          |   C:\f3.txt
5  |  05-05-1999          |   C:\f4.txt
6  |  06-05-1999          |   C:\f4.txt
```

I need to select all **file_paths**, where **file_date** is old and no other rows with this **file_path** with newer **file_date** exists

For example, if I have to fetch rows with dates older then 2019, my result should be like this:

```
file_path
C:\f1.txt
C:\f4.txt
```

I have a solution:

```
SELECT rslt.file_path
FROM mytable rslt
GROUP BY rslt.file_path
HAVING MAX(rslt.file_date) < '2019-01-01'
```

The problem is that this script takes ~2 minutes to returns ~62k of rows in a table, where I have 44.6 millions of rows, and simple script to take all rows older than the date (see below) takes 2-3 seconds

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE file_date < '2019-01-01'
```

So, is there any way to optimize my solution?

Answer (score 0):

How long does this take?

```
SELECT t.file_path
FROM mytable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable t2
                  WHERE t2.file_path = t.file_path AND t2.file_date >= '2019-01-01'
                 );
```

You want an index on `(file_path, file_date)` for best performance.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do a negation of your second faster query and do a `NOT IN`?

```sql
     SELECT rslt.file_path
     FROM mytable rslt
     WHERE rslt.file_path NOT IN
         (SELECT rslt2.file_path
          FROM mytable rslt2
          WHERE rslt2.file_path IS NOT NULL
          AND rslt2.file_date >= '2019-01-01')
     GROUP BY rslt.file_path;
```

`NOT IN` appears to get a bit funky if the selection pulls back nulls, so I put a `IS NOT NULL` in the where of the inner query as well, but it may not be necessary for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TargetDate     date    =   '01-01-2019'
DECLARE     @PathList   TABLE   (id int, file_date datetime, file_path varchar(255))
INSERT INTO @PathList   VALUES
            (1, '01-01-1999', 'C:\f1.txt')
        ,   (2, '01-01-2020', 'C:\f2.txt')
        ,   (3, '05-05-1999', 'C:\f3.txt')
        ,   (4, '05-05-2020', 'C:\f3.txt')
        ,   (5, '05-05-1999', 'C:\f4.txt')
        ,   (6, '06-05-1999', 'C:\f4.txt')
;

SELECT  DISTINCT
        PL.file_path
FROM            @PathList   PL                                        
    LEFT JOIN   @PathList   PH  ON  PH.file_path =  PL.file_path    
                                AND PH.file_date >= @TargetDate 
WHERE   
            PL.file_date    <   @TargetDate 
        AND PH.id           IS  NULL
```

Comment: The JOIN makes the trick: Exclude those that have the same path, but also newer dates.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
SELECT rslt.file_path, MAX(rslt.file_date) as Max_file_date
into #t
FROM mytable rslt
GROUP BY rslt.file_path

Select file_path 
From #t 
Where Max_file_date < '2019-01-01'
```

or try

```
SELECT rslt.file_path
into #t
FROM mytable rslt
WHERE file_date < '2019-01-01'
GROUP BY rslt.file_path
```